# What item creation feats should an Alchemist take?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, optimization, alchemist

I'm trying to plot out an alchemist build with the Clone Master archetype, particularly the feats.

I'd like to keep this character somewhat mirrored to another: the wizard in the party, and the alchemist's sibling, who is already slated to take Craft Wondrous Item and Inscribe Magical Tattoo. In order to do that, I'd like to just pick 2 feats. So I'm trying to decide what 2 item creation feats an alchemist would be suited to using, given their spell list.

Answer (score 7):

By RAW an alchemist don't have a caster level, so he doesn't qualify for the requirements to take any crafting feats.

You can read more about it in [this FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qdk) which states:

> Is an alchemist a spellcaster for the purpose of crafting magic items other than potions?
>   As written, no, alchemists are not spellcasters, and therefore can't select feats such as Craft Wondrous Item. 
>   The design team is aware that this creates some thematic problems with the idea of an alchemist creating golems and so on, and plan to examine this in the future.

That said, if you **really** want to craft magic items you could try to:

- Obtain a spell-like ability with a caster level high enought to qualify for the feat (usually the racial spell like have a caster level equal to your caracter level, so those are handy) or
- Take the master craftsman feat at level 5, and then the craft wonderous item (useless, since your wizard buddy already has it, probably 4 level sooner) or craft magic arms and armors

Comment: actually, they can. As proven by Paizo Creative Director, James Jacobs. the proof is found in the 2 posts provided here:
[Post one](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mz2b&page=1?How-does-the-alchemist-use-discoveries-that#4)
[post two](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=224?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#11198)

Comment: @Dann Both of those posts (from 2011) predate the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qdk) (2013).